# Trouble with some linq2sql generated T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql, sql-execution-plan

I'm having some trouble with SQL timeout for the following LINQ2SQL query:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2013-08-01 00:00:00.000");

Clients.Where(e => 
    (
        !Orders.Any(f => f.ClientId.Equals(e.Id) && f.OrderDate >= date)
        ||
        Comments.Any(f => f.KeyId.Equals(e.Id))
    )
).Count().Dump();
```

When running this in LinqPad it will take forever to finish and will become an SQL timeout if running on the server.

The SQL-code generated:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Clients] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Orders] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[ClientId] = [t0].[Id]) AND ([t1].[OrderDate] >= @p0)
    ))) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Comments] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[KeyId] = [t0].[Id]
    ))
```

Works fine in SQL-studio!

But:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Clients] AS [t0]
WHERE 

(NOT (EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [Orders] AS [t1] WHERE ([t1].[ClientId] = [t0].[Id]) AND ([t1].[OrderDate] >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000')))) 

OR  

(EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [Comments] AS [t2] WHERE [t2].[KeyId] = [t0].[Id]))
```

And will get me a the problem as actually running the query in LinqPad.

What is the difference of using `DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'` compared to using the constant date and how do I get my Linq2SQL to work?

EDIT:

See execution plans for both queries:

Timeouts:
[image: TIMEOUTS]

Fine:
[image: FINE]

Some other things I've noticed is that if I remove the NOT it works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Clients] AS [t0]
WHERE 

((EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [Orders] AS [t1] WHERE ([t1].[ClientId] = [t0].[Id]) AND ([t1].[OrderDate] >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000')))) 

OR  

(EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [Comments] AS [t2] WHERE [t2].[KeyId] = [t0].[Id]))
```

Or if I remove the OR EXISTS parts it also works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Clients] AS [t0]
WHERE 

((EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [Orders] AS [t1] WHERE ([t1].[ClientId] = [t0].[Id]) AND ([t1].[OrderDate] >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'))))
```

Thanks
/Niels

Comment: The `'2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'` in the second SQL code is just a string, not a `DateTime`

Comment: @Tico the string value will be cast to a DateTime when compared to a bonafide DateTime value. An error will be thrown if this is not possible and SQL server _should_ be smart enough to perform this cast ONCE rather than for every row, so that is not a factor here.

Comment: @Niels Bosma does the query ever finish in SSMS? It would be worth taking a look at the execution plan if so.

Comment: @DrewR Yes after 34minutes :(. I've attached an execution plan.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read the query plan in your screengrabs. Also, can you run the 34-minuter twice in a row and see if the timing changes for each execution (thinking plan caching)?

Comment: I don't see any execution plan..

Comment: Well I can see that the query plans are different, specifically around the access to the orders table. The query that performs fine is performing a Clustered Indes Scan whereas the timeout query is performing an index lookup, followed by an bookmark lookup. This is probably due to the fact that in the fine version a local variable is used and the query optimizer doesn't check the actual value of the date it just makes an assumption based upon the distribution of values. In the poor case it actually uses the actual value of the date to come up with a plan. So are the statistics up-to date?

Comment: You need an index on Orders(ClientID,OrderDate) or alternatively Orders(OrderDate,ClientID). Also Comments(KeyId).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to rebuild the index of OrderDate.

Answer (score 5):

Your Orders table must be fairly large.  You have an index on OrderDate right?
SQL Server actually generates 2 different execution plans in this example.  Or if it generates the same plan, SQL gives greatly different numbers of returned rows for the 2 statements.

```
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= @p0
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'
```

The first statement generates a parameterized query, plan optimizer will assume @p0 is unknown at the time and choose an execution plan that best fits unknown values.
The 2nd statement, optimizer will take into account that you supplied a fixed value.  SQL will look at the index distribution and estimate how many rows will be filtered by >= '2013-08-01'

Comment: Actually the order table isn't that big. Only 39998 rows. Yes, there's a Non-clustured, Non-unique index on OrderDate. Running your sql, it returns the same result, and the parametized one actually has a lot bigger subtree cost.

Comment: @NielsBosma Yes that's precisely the reason why one of your queries is timing out.  The queries are functionally identical, but their execution are different.

Answer (score 3):

The execution plan is not visible, but in general sql performance recommendation don't use negations it always be a hit in performance. In your case try to use the <= instead the negation with the >=

And if you use many or  it will hit your performance as well. Try to use subquerys as a work around to not use many or or negations.